# Is replacing a simple method (e.g vector::size()) by a const reference field a good idea?

Tags: c++

For example, this is my implementation of vector:

```
template<typename T, /*...*/>
class List {
private:
    /*...*/
    int count;
    int capacity;

public:
    /*constexpr int Count() noexcept {
        return count;
    }*/
    /*constexpr int Capacity() noexcept {
        return capacity;
    }*/

    const int& Count = count;
    const int& Capacity = capacity;

    /*...*/
}
```

Because these 2 methods just return a `private` field, ensuring that unable to be changed, and there's no other operations, checks or exceptions in function. Could I take the replace in this situation?

One of the disadvantages I've noticed is that 16 bytes is added for `List` due to the 2 references(pointers). Could it be optimized?

Comment: It's not a technique I would normally do (and have never needed to do).  There may be some sort of extraordinary circumstances that would make me consider this technique, but I cannot imagine what they would be.

Comment: What's wrong with using the functions? The compiler will certainly optimize them away, and you won't need to store references.

Comment: It is not a good idea, and as mentioned it is probably a de-optimize. One the one hand, compiler will typically inline calls to such small and trivial functions, one the other hand, save ref cost extra memory.

Comment: @jkb Just to omit brackets..

Comment: Feels like somebody did too much C#.

Comment: Think about what advantage you get. If omitting parenthesis worth 16 bytes of memory, then use it. However as a high performance oriented language like C++, it might not be considered.

Comment: By the way, C# are actually using getter and setter for properties under the hood, instead of using reference.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Not at all. A C# programmer wouldn’t even think of using references here.. partly because they don’t exist in C# like C++.

Comment: @user2864740 Still feels like an attempt at recreating the .NET BCL `List<T>` class.

Comment: I’ve nothing to counter that view.. oh well. So many interesting choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no benefit to adding reference-members to your class -- the public methods that you have commented out are more efficient, since the compiler will not be constrained by aliasing issues when optimizing them.   Also there are several drawbacks to using reference-members:

1. They increase the size of your class-objects (as you mentioned)
2. A caller might take the address of one of these member variables and hold onto it (e.g. `const int * myPtr = &myList.Count`), and then try to dereference that pointer after the `List` object has been destroyed, invoking undefined behavior.
3. Adding references as member-objects means that the C++ compiler won't generate a default assignment-operator for you; you'll have to define one manually if you want one.

Short, inline-defined methods (like the ones commented out in your posted code) are almost always optimized by the compiler such that there is no function-call overhead involved in calling them; therefore you won't get any performance gain by avoiding them.

Comment: 2. is not specific to reference members. A caller might do the same for non-reference member and it would be equally wrong. 3. is true, however in the example case of vector container implementation the assignment operator likely has to be user defined anyway.

Comment: Eerorika sure, but in this case the caller cannot do that because the non-reference members are private.

Comment: I agree that #2 is not specific to reference members. A caller might take the address of the *object* and hold on to it (e.g. `List * myPtr = &myList`), and then try to dereference that pointer after the `List` object has been destroyed, invoking undefined behavior. The caller messed up, not the class.

Answer (score 3):

> Could I take the replace in this situation?

You *could*.

> Is replacing a simple method (e.g vector::size()) by a const reference field a good idea?

No. It is a waste of memory.

Comment: Reference members are worse than simply wasting memory. Self-referencing members are... a bit closer to hell on earth than I personally like.